# How to import optional properties file for production in Spring config?

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to configure `Spring` to override some properties during production, but only(!) if the `production.properties` file is found and only for the properties it defines. But these contraints should only apply to this production file. All other property files should be required.

But I cannot import two different property resources within a spring configuration. What would I have to change?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:default.properties"})
@PropertySource({"file:production.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true) //Error: Duplicate annotation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `PropertySources` annotation, it's a container annotation that aggregates several `PropertySource` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your configuration file:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    Resource[] resources = new Resource[ ] {
            new ClassPathResource( "default.properties" ),
            new FileSystemResource("production.properties")
    };

    pspc.setLocations( resources );
    pspc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
    return pspc;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this set the `ignoreSourceNotFound` attribute to all of my property files? I'd like to apply it only to one specific.

Comment: ignoreSourceNotFound in this case would mean that if Spring encounters something like @Value("${prop.name}) and prop.name cannot be found in any of the properties files, then the application would not start. It doesn't mean that all properties needs to be present in all files